# Visualforce Page custom look up

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have used this blog post as a reference to create a custom look up visualforce page http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.com/2010/09/visualforce-lookup.html
Now I have a requirement which says that I have to populate another field based on the selected look up value.

In the above mentioned blog, using the look up text field Account Name is getting populated. Now based on the selected look up value I also want another field Account Number to be auto populated. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I have:

```
<apex:page id="SearchAccount" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="SearchAccountController">

    <script>
        var newWin = null;

        function openLookupPopup(Name, id) {
            var url = "/apex/LookupExamplePopup?namefield=" + name + "&idfield=" + id;
            newWin = window.open(url, 'Popup', 'height=500,width=600,left=100,top=100,resizable=no,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,status=no');
            if (window.focus) {
                newWin.focus();
            }
            return false;
        }

        function closeLookupPopup() {

            if (null != newWin) {
                newWin.close();
            }
         populateNumber();     
        }
    </script>

    <apex:actionFunction name="populateNumber" action="{!PopulateAccNumber}" rerender="accinfo, msgs" />

   <apex:outputPanel> 
   <apexoutputText value="Name"/>
   <apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:inputHidden value="{!accountId}" id="targetId" />
        <apex:inputText value="{!laccountName}" id="targetName" onFocus="this.blur()"/>

        </apexoutputPanel>
        <a href="#" onclick="openLookupPopup('{!$Component.targetName}', '{!$Component.targetId}'); return false">Lookup</a> 
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputText value="{!accountnumber}" id="accinfo"/>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public String accountnumber { get; set; }
public String accountid { get; set; }

public void PopulateAccNumber() {
    Account acc = [Select id, Name, AccountNumber from Account where id=:accountid];
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and what you have already tried in order to accomplish your goal.

Comment: Is the field acctual lookup?
Do you have to populate it in VF page or on save action?

Comment: I am not using a look up field. it is an text field on visualforce and I am populating the value using Javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell you have to submit the form after the lookup is populated and query the fields you need back from the database.

There's another post on my blog that covers this:

http://bobbuzzard.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/retrieve-related-object-fields.html

As you are using my custom lookup, you won't be able to use the actionsupport to post the form back, instead I'd create an actionfunction and execute that from the closeLookupPopup() JavaScript method.

Comment: Bob, Thank you for your comment. My Javascript skills are just manageable to say the least. So taking your advise I edited my code but I am still not able to populate my account number. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are pretty close - I suspect the fact that you have nested the actionfunction inside the inputtext is the problem - move that outside the outputpanel and it should fire. I'd also move the populateNumber() to the end of the closeLookupPopup method, as otherwise there could be a race condition there with posting back the page and closing the window.
 If that doesn't work, use the chrome inspector or firefox web console to see if you have any JavaScript errors.

Comment: Also, you are rerendering accinfo but I can't see that anywhere in your code - is that an outputpanel, or should the outputtext that prints accountNumber have that id?

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned but it is still not getting populated.

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Great - glad to be of help. The way that stack exchange works is that you would now upvote this and select it as the answer using the tick button.  That way anyone coming to this question would know there was a solution.